# How to get string from ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

How I can get the selected item data in `onItemLongClick` ?

```
  listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    //              
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Did you got solution @Mickey Tin ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int pos, long mylng) {
    String selectedFromList =(lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
    // this is your selected item
  }                 
});
```

Comment: selectedFromList = android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4052cf70

Comment: if you are using array to form a list then using list item selected position you can get value from array

Answer (score 2):

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
    {
         String item = ArryList.get(arg2); 
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item,
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
         return false;
     }
 });
```

Comment: What is pos here ? I think here arg2 is used instead of pos.

Comment: cannot convert from Object to String

Answer (score 0):

If you parse set of data from xml, json, database, etc it's better to create custom model i.e.
your model:

```
public class YourModel
{
    private int id = -1;
    private String title = "";

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

In activity:

```
private YourModel yourModel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id)
        {
            detailsModel = ((YourAdapter) lstView.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, yourModel.getTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```